# React 'toggleBurgerMenu' is not defined no-undef

Tags: reactjs

I am a total newbie on react. I am trying to use a functional app and wanted to use the function `toggleBurgerMenu()`. The problem, I am not sure what else I need to define it. Should I use `props.toggleBurgerMenu()`?

```
import React from 'react'
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import './Header.scss'

const Header = (props) => {

    toggleBurgerMenu = () => {
        document.querySelector('.navbar-menu').classList.toggle('is-active');
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <header>
                <nav className="navbar" role="navigation" aria-label="main navigation">

                    <div id="navbarBasicExample" className="navbar-menu">
                        <div className="navbar-start">

                            <Link to="/home" className="navbar-item" onClick={()=> this.toggleBurgerMenu()}>Home</Link>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </nav>
            </header>
        </div>
    )

}


export default Header
```

Appreciate any help. thank you

Comment: Since you are using functional comp, you can not use this. try
onClick={()=>toggleBurgerMenu()}

Comment: Thanks, I followed the wrong instruction?

Answer (score 0):

You need to define your toggleBurgerMenu function like this `const toggleBurgerMenu = () => { document.querySelector('.navbar-menu').classList.toggle('is-active'); }`. And then you can use it in the onClick Event like this `<Link to="/home" className="navbar-item" onClick={toggleBurgerMenu}>Home</Link>`

Answer (score 0):

with react the best thing to do is not using document you could use a ref instead, but in this case you can add some state and update the classname

here is an easy example

```
const Header = (props) => {
    /** function to set the state of the button */
    const [isActive, setIsActive] = useState(initialState)
    return (
        <div>
            <header>
                <nav className="navbar" role="navigation" aria-label="main navigation">
                    {/**if its true we add is-active class there are several package to this*/}
                    <div id="navbarBasicExample" className={`navbar-menu ${isActive ? 'is-active' : ''}`}>
                        <div className="navbar-start">

                            <Link to="/home" className="navbar-item" onClick={() => setIsActive(prev => !prev.setIsActive)}>Home</Link>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </nav>
            </header>
        </div>
    )

}


export default Header
```